# Multipart messages passing in ZMQ

Tags: c++, zeromq

I am trying to do a multipart message passing in ZeroMQ. More specifically, I want to pass an `int` followed by a pointer to a vector `vector<T>*`. I came up with the following code:

```
zmq::zmq_msg_t               msg1;
zmq::zmq_msg_init_data (    &msg1,  i, sizeof(   i ), NULL, NULL );
zmq::zmq_send ( publisher_, &msg, ZMQ_SNDMORE );

zmq::zmq_msg_t               msg2;
zmq::zmq_msg_init_data            ptr, sizeof( ptr ), NULL, NULL ); 
zmq::zmq_send (          s, &msg, 0 );
```

I am not sure if this will work since it seems that the data parameter in the `zmq_send` method is of type `void*` and I am sending just a value.

Also, can anyone tell me how do I separately receive these two messages on the other side? [Zero-copy and Multi-part Messages](http://zeromq.org/blog:zero-copy) only shows how to get the messages when the number of messages to get is unknown. But in my case it is two. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You want to use init_size, with the correct zize, as you did, and then copy the integer or the pointer to internal msg buffer. On the otherside just cast it or copy it back to integer/pointer